# Optimal allocation of Stats from equipment

Tags: guild-wars-2

For maximum survivability, is it better to get gear with only Vitality, or should you evenly distribute between Vitality and Toughness?

I have read that Vitality seems to be a lot better than Toughness.

Also, between Power and Precision, is it more effective to go all out Strengh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Guild Wars 2 is similar to other games, its still early so the exact combat formulas aren't well understood, but usually its a trade off where vitality (HP) dominates early on, but once you have enough HP, toughness/defense/armor becomes more important.

The metric you want to use to maximize survivability is effective hp which takes into account both vitality and toughness. The same goes with power/precision for calculating max DPS.

Comment: Wait for someone to start theorycrafting, and creating graphs and "optimal" points for each "usage". Or, if you have plenty time, friends, and is very good at math, do it yourself.
It tends to be way more complex according the number of "variables" included in each "formula".
But i guess @Hao Kung is right. HP tends to be mandatory until a certain ammount, after that point, it is considered to be "overkill", and them, armor starts to apply better

Comment: So for earlier levels ~1-40, go with power and vitality?

Comment: Yes, for now i would just stack raw damage and hp, which is power and vit.  Eventually at some point it makes sense to start investing in both crit and crit damage as well.